# Number of indirect employees interview challenge in Python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, recursion

An example interview question I have seen come up several times is

> Given a mapping of employee_id to boss_id (for direct chain of command
>   only), return how many employees each boss indirectly manages.

I have found several solutions in SQL but can't find any examples of pythonic approaches.

More detailed problem definition:

Imagine that we have a dict containing the employee_id and the boss_id. In the example below C is manager of A, C is also manager of B, F is manager of C and so on. F is the manager of themselves and therefore the root of the hierarchy (i.e. the CEO).  Each employee directly reports to exactly one manager.

```
emp_boss_map = dict([
 ("A","C"),
 ("B","C"),
 ("C","F"),
 ("D","E"),
 ("E","F"),
 ("F","F")])
```

Write a function to build a dictionary of the quantity of employees under each employee, not just their direct reports.

Output should be the following for example above:

```
{A:0,B:0,C:2,D:0,E:1,F:5}
```

How would one approach this problem in Python?

UPDATE:
Upon @prune 's suggestion I reversed the dict using

```
newdict = {}
for key, value in emp_boss_map.items():
    for string in value:
        newdict.setdefault(string, []).append(key)
```

Which returns
    {'C': ['A', 'B'], 'E': ['D'], 'F': ['C', 'E', 'F']}

Answer (score 1):

This is a closure problem on a tree.  First and foremost, invert (reverse) the dictionary.  From then, it's a straightforward count of nodes in each sub-tree, a recursive algorithm on each individual node: recur on each child, sum their return values, add 1 for each child, and that's the total direct reports for the current node.

Does that get you moving?

---

```
full_report = {}

def report_count(node):
    global full_report
    report_list = newdict[node]
    count = len(report_list)     # start with quantity of direct reports

    # Find number of reports for each of those reports
    for report in report_list:
    count += report_count(report)

    full_report[node] = count          # add entry for this node to global count list
    return count + len(report_list)    # return this count to supervisor
```

I've left a lot of details open for you, such as finding all of the root nodes (from the original dictionary) and perhaps finding something better than a global variable for the master list.

Does that get you to the final solution?

Comment: I was able to the reverse the dict (see update) but am quite confused about the structure of the subsequent steps. Is there any way you could provide an example using code above?

Comment: This is my first encounter with trees. What is 'node' in your example referring to with the regards to my data example? The keys in the reverse dict perhaps?

Comment: Yes, a "node" is an entry for a particular employee.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by reversing a dictionary and traversing it recursively till the end.

```
result_count=[]
def get_me_the_children(root):
    if reverse_d.get(root,0) == 0:
        return
    for _ in reverse_d.get(root,0):
        if _== root:
            continue
        else:
            get_me_the_children(_)
            print(_,end=" ")
            result_count.append(_)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_d = {"A":"A","B":"A","C":"B","D":"B","E":"D","F":"E"}
    reverse_d={}
    result_count_dict = {}

    for key,values in input_d.items():
        reverse_d.setdefault(values,[])
        reverse_d[values].append(key)

    #reverse_d = {'A': ['A', 'B'], 'B': ['C', 'D'], 'D': ['E'], 'E': ['F']}

    for key,value in input_d.items():
        result_count=[]
        print(key,end=": ")
        get_me_the_children(key)
        result_count_dict[key] = len(result_count)
        print("")

    print(result_count_dict) #{'A': 5, 'B': 4, 'C': 0, 'D': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 0}

    """output:
        A: C F E D B 
        B: C F E D 
        C: 
        D: F E 
        E: F 
        F:  
    """
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def m1(dict):
    new_dict = {}
    keys_list = {keys for keys in dict.keys()}
    for key, val in dict.items():
        if key==val:
            continue
        if val not in new_dict.keys():
            new_dict[val] = 1
        else:
            new_dict[val] = new_dict[val] + 1
        if key in new_dict.keys():
            new_dict[val] = new_dict[val] + new_dict[key]
    for keys in keys_list:
        if keys not in new_dict.keys():
            new_dict[keys]=0
    print(new_dict)


emp_boss_map={'A': 'C', 'B': 'C', 'C': 'F', 'D': 'E', 'E': 'F', 'F': 'F'}
m1(emp_boss_map)
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).